# How does my app work when targetSdk is higher than compile sdk

Tags: android, targetsdkversion

I would think that to target an sdk, the compile sdk would have to be at or higher than the target sdk. Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

I recently changed the target sdk to be higher than the compile sdk and the app still worked. I do not understand how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a long post from one of the Android devs](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) explaining the whole thing, what you should and shouldn't change, and why!

There's this little formula about the relationship between the different numbers:

`minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion`

But I think the point there is this is how it **should** be. The `minSdk` acts as a minimum API level, and `compileSdk` is the version of the API that the app is actually compiled against, making it an effective maximum "included" API level (can't add features that aren't in it yet!).

`targetSdk` is meant to act as a control for features - you can (and should) compile against the most recent API for bug fixes etc, but actual behaviour changes can be restricted by limiting `targetSdk` to an earlier API level:

> **targetSdkVersion**
>
> The most interesting of the three, however, is `targetSdkVersion`. `targetSdkVersion` is the main way Android provides forward compatibility by not applying behavior changes unless the `targetSdkVersion` is updated. This allows you to use new APIs (as you did update your `compileSdkVersion` right?) prior to working through the behavior changes.

So really it works like "don't enable any features from APIs higher than this". In which case, it doesn't really *make sense* to set it higher than `compileSdk` - there aren't any extra features available beyond the API level you're compiling against. Plus you shouldn't be raising `targetSdk` without testing against that API level - which you obviously haven't, if you're not compiling against that API!

So I guess there's nothing *stopping you* from setting `targetSdk` at whatever level you want, it's really `compileSdk` setting that upper limit on what actually gets into the app. There just isn't any good reason to set `targetSdk` higher than that.

Comment: What you call "features from an higher API" is usually a restriction. IMHO targetSDK is more a value that enables some sort of compatibility mode for running older apps on newer devices. That is also the reason why Google enforces a minimum targetSDK version, to make sure newly published apps are adapted to the new restrictions on newer Android versions instead of keeping the old compatibility mode that is often easier to use because of less restrictions.

Comment: @Robert oh yeah, I didn't mean to imply it's only new capabilities or whatever - just "features of that API" including restrictions, limitations, deprecated stuff etc. That's also why you need to test when you bump up the `targetSdkVersion`, even if you're not using any new stuff - it usually will enforce behaviour changes that you need to be handling